# Finding a 'part' word with RegEx

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I want to find chapter and find words in a sentence.

```
sentence1 = 'chapter1'
sentence2 = 'chapter 1'
sentence3 = 'part1'
sentence4 = 'part 1'
sentence5 = 'party'

re.search('((\bchapter\b|\bpart$\b)|[ ^a-z*,0-9]+)+', sentence5)
```

But I don't want to get some words like `'part(y)'`. I mean code should find first 4 sentences but 5th sentence shouldn't be find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ is end of line, not word boundary.

`^((\bchapter)|(\bpart))\s?[0-9]`

Comment: Yes that's the correct solution. Thanks for solution. I told my problem little bit wrong. 

I should find all 'part' and 'chapter' words in a sentence but it can be different types. 
Such as: 
'part hello world'
'hello world part'
'part: hello world ' and etc.

Comment: force boundaries at the start and end, but allow an optional space/number `((\bchapter)|(\bpart))\s?[0-9]?\b`
I